# Why can't I properly read 32bit registry values in HKCU on 64bit machine?

Tags: c#, python, windows-7, registry

I'm stumped on a windows 7 registry problem and while various questions and answers get me some of the way there, nothings I've seen addresses my particular issue.  I don't know if other windows versions affects this problem, but we all have win7x64 machines.

We have a wide variety of tools at our work, some C++, some C#, some python (2.6), etc.  We also run a mix of 32 and 64 bit tools.  In the past, we've happily stored registry information in `HKLM`.  We've been working on moving stuff into `HKCU`.  We've had a lot of discussions about whether to do this, affects on `UAC`, etc.  We really want to try and make this move.  That said:

We are having trouble reading/writing registry keys out of `HKCU/software/CompanyABC/App`.  We have a setup `app` write in python that writes out registry keys to the above location using `_winreg`.  Whether or not we specify `KEY_WRITE`|`KEY_WOW64_32KEY` or just KEY_WRITE, the values get written to `HKCU/Software/WOW6432Node/companyABC/app`.  Fine.

Then I have a C# app that tries to read these values.  Using `Microsoft.Win32.Registry`, I open the subkey ('HKCU/Software/CompanyABC/app') and I don't see my values.  Turns out that I'm seeing the following behavior:

- When reading/writing registry keys from `HKLM`, this stuff all just works.  The python app will write to`HKLM/Softare/Wow6432Node/CompanyABC/app`, and the C# code will read from that location.  This all makes proper sense too, given how we are building our C# apps, and writing the registry values via python
- Reading/writing the registry values from HKCU, I get different behavior.  The `_winreg` functions will write to`HKCU/Sofrware/Wow6432Node/CompanyABC/app`, but the C# app will read from `HKCU/Software/CompanyABC/app`.  The C# app is built as an x86 app (not Any CPU and not x64) so I assumed that the app would get properly redirected to the `wow6432Node`, but it doesn't seem to.

after some investigation, it appears that `HKCU/Software` is different.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384253%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) article seems to indicate that this area is "shared" and not redirected.  If that is the case, then I cannot understand why our python app (again, using _winreg) is writing to a location in HKCU that uses the `Wow6432Node` - it seems like it should be writing it without that redirection in place.  I suppose that it could be a bug in`_winreg`.

I really want to avoid tacking on `WOW6432Node` explicitly in our tools, but that is where I am at today.  Can anyone explain to me how I can make registry accesses from 32 and 64 bit processes into `HKCU` work correctly without having to resort to hard coded paths into the 32-bit hive?

Comment: When I first switched to Windows Vista, the whole registry virtualization system (on top of 32/64-bit issues) made me decide never to use the registry again.  I understand this may not be possible, but if you *can* switch to something else (e.g. a configuration file), I strongly recommend to do so.

Comment: Can't reproduce this. For me, Python 2.6.6 (32 and 64 bit) on Windows 7 64 bit read/write to/from HKCU/Software/companyABC/app as expected (not HKCU/Software/WOW6432Node/companyABC/app).

Comment: Thanks cgohlke.  I'll take another look at what is going on here.  I appreciate the followup.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in your Python registry wrapper. HKCU\Software is not redirected. Try with plain win32 using ctypes to confirm this.

Comment: Did we get a resolution on this? I'm interested as to the root cause if it's not a Registry redirect funny.

Comment: Looks like PEBKAC.  I ran tests, saw the results that I posted about.  After cgohlke said the problem was not reproducable, I couldn't reproduce it either.  I left for Thanksgiving, came back and it's behaving as it should be.  *shrug*  I don't know what happened with my original tests, but they were clearly wrong.

Comment: Could have been a target machine issue possibly? If your target machine isn't set to "Any CPU", and is set specifically to "x86" the path becomes redirected per my tests.

Answer (score 4):

I understand from the comments on the question that this issue has gone away, for anyone else that encounters this question, you can use [Microsoft.Win32.OpenBaseKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey.aspx) to specify whether to open the 64 or 32-bit portion of the registry when running on a 64-bit machine even if your process is running as a 32-bit process.

If you always want to access the keys in the NON-WOW6432Node section of the registry, then you can safely set the View parameter of OpenBaseKey to [RegistryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx).Registry64. This will work correctly on both 64 and 32-bit OSes.