# How to check outlook is the default mail client

Tags: delphi, outlook, delphi-xe2

I use this code to check if outlook is the default mail client:

```
Function IsOutlookIsDefaultEmailPrg:Boolean;
var
  reg: TRegistry;
  key : string;
begin
  Result := False;
  with TRegistry.Create do
  TRY
    RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if OpenKeyReadOnly('Software\Clients\Mail') then
    begin
      key := Uppercase(ReadString('')); //default value
    end;
    result :=  (Pos('MICROSOFT OUTLOOK',Key) > 0);
  FINALLY
    Free;
  END;
end;
```

it works in general, but on some pc's it has been reported not to work, I checked and the registry key was there.

Is `Pos` case sensitive? Any idea why this cannot work at times? Any better suggestion?

Comment: Is your program 32 bit or 64 bit? What OS is running on the machines where this code fails? By any chance is it Vista?

Comment: Check this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203067%28VS.85%29.aspx). It applies from Windows XP up to Windows 7. Not sure about Windows 8.

Comment: Yes, Pos is case sensitive

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes `Pos` is case sensitive, i got confused. I think that HKCU issue is the problem, i hope to have the solution soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see you are using the HKLM key to check the default client but this can be user depended, so you should really check the HKCU entry (and fall back to HKLM if HKCU does not have the entry).
I also removed the `With` statement and used the `ContainsText` (include `StrUtils` unit) function instead of `Pos` :

```
function IsOutlookTheDefaultEmailClient:Boolean;
var
  Reg : TRegistry;    
begin
  Result := False;
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    // first check HKCU
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('Software\Clients\Mail') then
     begin
      Result := ContainsText(Reg.ReadString(''), 'Microsoft Outlook');
      Reg.CloseKey;
     end
    // fall back to HKLM
   else
    begin
     Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
     // this part is susceptible to registry virtualization and my need elevation!
     if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('Software\Clients\Mail') then
      begin
       Result := ContainsText(Reg.ReadString(''), 'Microsoft Outlook');
       Reg.CloseKey;
      end;
    end;  
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**EDIT**

The only time this code can fail is when [Registry virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) comes into play. This is typical in UAC scenarios.
Please check on a failing computer if this key exists in regedit:

```
HKCU\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail
```

if that is the case, your application will read this key and not the real HKLM key. The only solution is request elevation or run your application as administrator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain me how the modified function can give a different result since i am just trying to read a value (and not write)?

Comment: in 2 win7 machines i tried with both functions (my one and the modified one by whosrdaddy) and they both return True.

Comment: @user193655 And what does the key contain?

Comment: If you need to do HKCU and then HKLM fallback, then you should show that. But I don't see HKCU settings on my machine. Where is this documented.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, actually, potentially there are both a HKLM and a HKCU subkey for this, although I am not completely sure which one the OP needs. Check the link I posted in a comment to the question.

Comment: @GuillemVicens What i need is know if Outlook is the default mail client, ignoring how it has been installed, so probably  double check about it is better if i check for both keys and then put them in `OR` condition, so if any one is foudn i mark Outlook as default, does this make sense?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the reason why you don't see HKCU? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216472/why-cant-i-properly-read-32bit-registry-values-in-hkcu-on-64bit-machine

Comment: @user HKCU\Software\Classes is **not** redirected. It is shared.

Comment: @user193655, the link I posted says HKCU has higher precedence than HKLM for this case.

Comment: I accept this answer only now since i realize it solves my problem. On some pcs where multiple users access in fact i realize that HKLM setting is not reliable and the "escalated check" performed in the provided solution is the way to go. It works on windows 10 too.

Answer (score 2):

This is my understanding of the issues:

1. The `Pos` function is case-sensitive. So if the value is `Microsoft Outlook` then your test will not find it. You should instead use [`ContainsText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.ContainsText). Not only does that do what you want, but it is much more readable than `Pos()>0`.
2. The [system checks first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203067.aspx#email_reg) in `HKCU\Software\Clients\Mail`. If no default mail client is found there, then it checks in `HKLM\Software\Clients\Mail`. You should do likewise.
3. On Windows 7 and later, both `HKCU\Software\Clients` and `HKLM\Software\Clients\Mail` are [shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253.aspx). On earlier versions of Windows they are [redirected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253.aspx). There is potential for errors there. You should use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to access the 64 bit view of the registry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, problems are on Windows XP in fact. So what you suggest i do?

Comment: I suggest that you find out what the registry looks like on those machines and see if you can come up with a reason for that