# Python - reading registry - 32 and 64-bit

Tags: python, registry

I would like to know what is the best way to prepare a 32-bit EXE (build from Python script) which can read registry key regardless of user's system (32- or 64-bit Windows).
I tried and it works if I have 64-bit program and 64-bit system. After I changed it to 32-bit program, it doesn't read registry key (or it has Access denied).
Any suggestion how to handle this?
There are some solutions for C(*), but I can't find this for Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I properly read 32bit registry values in HKCU on 64bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216472/why-cant-i-properly-read-32bit-registry-values-in-hkcu-on-64bit-machine)

Comment: Similar yes, but I can't find this in Python. Until now, I use OpenKeyEx and QueryValueEx, but I can't find what parameters should I use.